# Quick (sparse) matrix construction by certain vector elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two numpy vectors **a** and **b** and want to construct a (ideally sparse) matrix **C** by something like:

`C[i,j] = (a[j]>b[j])*(a[i]+b[j])`

So only those elements where a certain relation between the j-indices are met will then be calculated by using some other elements. Again, this is easy by looping of i & j, but I'd like to know if there is a more efficient "numpy/scipy"-way? Simply put, I couldn't find out how to handle the differency in the indices involved.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I should have insisted on a [MCVE], but I'll make one

To arrays of the same size:

```
In [232]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
In [233]: b = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
```

the `a[j]>b[j]` part of your calculation:

```
In [234]: a>b
Out[234]: 
array([ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False])
```

the summation part, `a[i]+b[j]`:

```
In [235]: a[:,None]+b
Out[235]: 
array([[ 9,  9, 10, 14, 13, 11, 11, 12,  9, 14],
       [ 4,  4,  5,  9,  8,  6,  6,  7,  4,  9],
       [ 7,  7,  8, 12, 11,  9,  9, 10,  7, 12],
       [10, 10, 11, 15, 14, 12, 12, 13, 10, 15],
       [12, 12, 13, 17, 16, 14, 14, 15, 12, 17],
       [12, 12, 13, 17, 16, 14, 14, 15, 12, 17],
       [ 6,  6,  7, 11, 10,  8,  8,  9,  6, 11],
       [11, 11, 12, 16, 15, 13, 13, 14, 11, 16],
       [ 7,  7,  8, 12, 11,  9,  9, 10,  7, 12],
       [12, 12, 13, 17, 16, 14, 14, 15, 12, 17]])
```

Setting the desired columns to 0:

```
In [236]: _[:,np.nonzero(a>b)] = 0
In [237]: _
Out[237]: 
array([[ 0,  9, 10, 14, 13,  0, 11, 12,  9, 14],
       [ 0,  4,  5,  9,  8,  0,  6,  7,  4,  9],
       [ 0,  7,  8, 12, 11,  0,  9, 10,  7, 12],
       [ 0, 10, 11, 15, 14,  0, 12, 13, 10, 15],
       [ 0, 12, 13, 17, 16,  0, 14, 15, 12, 17],
       [ 0, 12, 13, 17, 16,  0, 14, 15, 12, 17],
       [ 0,  6,  7, 11, 10,  0,  8,  9,  6, 11],
       [ 0, 11, 12, 16, 15,  0, 13, 14, 11, 16],
       [ 0,  7,  8, 12, 11,  0,  9, 10,  7, 12],
       [ 0, 12, 13, 17, 16,  0, 14, 15, 12, 17]])
```

Oops, I got that switched, I should have set the other columns to 0.

But we don't have to do this in separate steps:

```
In [238]: (a>b)*(a[:,None]+b)
Out[238]: 
array([[ 9,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [10,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [12,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [12,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [11,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [12,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

This calculation depends heavily on `broadcasting`.  If you aren't familiar with that, it won't make much sense.

The arrays:

```
In [239]: a
Out[239]: array([5, 0, 3, 6, 8, 8, 2, 7, 3, 8])
In [240]: b
Out[240]: array([4, 4, 5, 9, 8, 6, 6, 7, 4, 9])
```

The fact that a lot (or just some) of the columns will be 0 doesn't make much difference when doing whole-array `numpy` calculations.  It usually simpler and faster to pass the whole arrays through.

You could iterate on columns, and just do the addition for selected ones.  No need to iterate on rows.  But usually this will be slower than [238]:

```
In [245]: c =  np.zeros((10,10),int)
     ...: for j in range(10):
     ...:     if a[j]>b[j]:
     ...:         c[:,j] = a + b[j]
```

or moving the comparison outside the loop:

```
In [249]: c =  np.zeros((10,10),int)
     ...: m = a>b
     ...: for j,v in enumerate(m):
     ...:     if v:
     ...:         c[:,j] = a + b[j]
```

Better yet:

```
In [253]: c =  np.zeros((10,10),int)
     ...: idx = np.nonzero(a>b)[0]
     ...: print(idx)
     ...: c[:,idx] = a[:,None] + b[idx]
```

For some degree of sparsity this last one might be faster, but not here:

```
In [256]: %%timeit
     ...: c =  np.zeros((10,10),int)
     ...: idx = np.nonzero(a>b)[0]
     ...: c[:,idx] = a[:,None] + b[idx]
17.7 µs ± 772 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [258]: timeit (a>b)*(a[:,None]+b)
10.7 µs ± 139 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using loops. There is one property you can make use of thought: The condition `a[j]>b[j]` tells us if a whole column can be zero, so if we're using `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data,(i,j)))` it would make sense to make an outer loop over the columns:

```
data=[]
i=[]
j=[]
for jx = ...:
    if a[j]>b[j]:
        for ix = ...: # this whole loop can be skipped if the condition is not satisfied
            data.append(a[i]+a[j])
            i.append(ix)
            j.append(jx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I should have emphasized, that this process will be running very often and as far as I thought, appending is one of the rather slow processes, isn't it? 
And that will also run single-threaded, right?

Comment: In this case it should be easy to parallelize the loop over `jx`. Appending is not slow in that it is an O(1) operation, but if that is an issue you could also consider preallocating `i,j` as `np.array`s and depending on how `a` and `b` are distributed you could speed it up by vectorizing the second loop, maybe even making the concession to the sparseness that for every `j` where `a[j]>b[j]` you just introduce a full column. But these are things that only you can decide as we don't know enough about your problem and your tools!

Comment: Depending on your use case it might not even be necessary to implement the creation of these matrices but maybe only implement a method that computes the result of a matrix multiplication. But as I said, that is not something we can judge from an outside perspective. Alternatively you can try to vectorize everything, which might even be faster, but that depends again on how big `a` and `b` are, what kind of distribution of numbers they have etc. What I provided here was just what I'd consider the most "numpy/scipy"-way .

Comment: The OP did say he had `numpy` arrays.  We generally try to avoid (python) loops when working with arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj In general this is true, however in this case it sounds like we'd deal with sparse data. Let's say only 0.01% of times the conditoin `a[j]>b[j]` holds, and `a` and `b` are large enough. Then we might actually *have* to work with loops as the whole matrix might not even fit into memory. And memory is probably an issue if OP already wants to work with sparse data structures. But that is just a guess as we don't know the exact situation that OP has.